# the limit of normal distribution function n(0, n)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $F_n$ is the distribution function of N(0,n). Then when n goes to infinity, the $F_n$ goes to $F(x)=1/2$? Why? How to see that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z_n$ be a normal variable with mean zero and variance $n$. This means that $\frac1{\sqrt n} Z_n$ is a standard normal variable, so is distributed like $Z_1$. Therefore,

$$
\begin{align}
F_n(x)&=P(Z_n\le x)
\\&=P(\tfrac1{\sqrt n}Z_n\le \tfrac1{\sqrt n}x)
\\&= P(Z_1\le \tfrac1{\sqrt n}x)\\&=F_1(\tfrac1{\sqrt n}x)\end{align}
$$
Since $x/\sqrt n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, and $F_1$ is continuous, we conclude $F_n(x)\to F_1(0)=\tfrac12$ as $n\to\infty$.